# How to merge large dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given `pandas` DataFrame `df`:

```
           paper    reference   count
9384155    p25      r50         1
7434371    p98      r9          78
7433400    p7       r27         5
7431765    p101     r91         501
7422256    p22      r5          91
...
```

A dictionary `df_dict` that subsets `df` by `count` is created:

```
df_dict={key:df[df['count']==key] for key in df['count'].unique()}

df_dict

{1:          paper       reference   count
 9384155     p10         r72         1
 7434371     p94         r5          1
 7433400     p71         r90         1
...
 7431765     p3          r113        1
 7422256     p78         r18         1
[5693 rows x 3 columns],

2:           paper       reference   count
 3817395     p102        r6          2
 4726581     p54         r3          2
...
```

I wanted to use `.merge()` operation per sub-DataFrames in `df_dict`:

```
for key, value in df_dict.items():
  c = df_dict[key]
  c = c.drop(['count'], axis=1)
  pairs = c.merge(c,on=['reference'])
  pairs = pairs[pairs["paper_x"] < pairs["paper_y"]]
  pairs = pairs.groupby(["paper_x", "paper_y"]).count().reset_index()

  pairs = pairs.drop(['count_x'], axis=1)

  pairs.columns = ["paper1", "paper2", "common"]

  refs = c.groupby(["paper"]).count().reset_index()
  refs = refs.drop(['count'], axis=1)
  refs.columns = ["paper", "count", "freq"]

  result = pairs.merge(refs, how="left", left_on="paper1", right_on="paper")
  result = result.merge(refs, how="left", left_on="paper2", right_on="paper")
  result = result[["paper1", "freq_x", "paper2", "freq_y", "count", "common"]]
  result.columns = ["paper1", "freq1", "paper2", "freq2", "count", "common"]

  key += 1
```

but the operation returns a single big DataFrame with incorrect values. How can I perform this operation and still maintain a dictionary form, separated by `count`?

Comment: Since you are not giving a proper example of an input and desired output, it is hard to tell what may be the problem. Also, you probably can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to simplify what you are doing.

Comment: can you explain what is expected output, quite unusual to merge a dataframe with itself